# android listview: how to get rid of the ticks?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to get a simple listview without any ticks/checkmarks. How do I get rid of them?? Have tried changing background colour, doesn't make a difference.

Here's my xml file for the list activity layout...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#ff868686"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView       
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:stackFromBottom="false"
    android:transcriptMode="normal"
    android:listSelector="#ffee8c00"
    />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the xml file that you are using with your Adapter?

Comment: Ah, fixed it - in the activity .java file I had:
    
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, sites));

which I have now changed to:

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sites));

Answer (score -1):

In your CSS
    li {list-style-type: none;}